# Derivation of FFT

Tags: fourier-analysis

Can someone please share a link or source where I can find the derivation of FFT(base-2) from the DFT. I need to put this in latex for my thesis and am finding so many different explanations that I don't know which one to use.

Comment: The exposition at Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm%23The_radix-2_DIT_case) seems OK?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found a better [link](ftp://www.comm-tec.com/oops/ismar/Benthos_chirp2_win2000_install/DSPDriver/web/pdfs/tech/fft-bench.pdf).
Thank you for your help.